# How to prevent an empty Attachment from uploading

Tags: attachment

I have code which uses a custom object (Product_Review_Attachment__c) which I created to allow me to give a Description__c and Label (Document_Type__c) to an attachment.

Right now, it is creating a new Product_Review_Attachment__c record - and then it is creating an Attachment and including values from the new record to the Attachment.

But I don't want it to attempt to create the Attachment if there is no attachment placed into the VisualForce page being used. I can prevent it from creating the new Product_Review_Attachment__c record without a Description with the IF statement I have checking the Description in the processUpload portion. But I would like to be able to check if there is an Attachment as well.

Here is the Apex :

```
public class UploadAttachmentControllerProdRev {

    public String selectedType {get;set;}
    public Boolean selectedAwesomeness {get;set;}
    public String description {get;set;}
    private Product_Review__c contact {get;set;} 
    public String fileName {get;set;}
    public Blob fileBody {get;set;}

    public String contactproduct {get;set;}

    public UploadAttachmentControllerProdRev(ApexPages.StandardController controller) { 
        this.contact = (Product_Review__c)controller.getRecord();

    }   

    // creates a new Product_Review_Attachment__c record
    private Database.SaveResult saveCustomAttachment() {
        Product_Review_Attachment__c obj = new Product_Review_Attachment__c();
        obj.Product_Review__c = contact.Id; 
        obj.Product__c = contact.Product__c;
        obj.Description__c = description;
        obj.Document_type__c = selectedType;
        // fill out cust obj fields
        return Database.insert(obj);
    }

    // create an actual Attachment record with the Product_Review_Attachment__c as parent
    private Database.SaveResult saveStandardAttachment(Id parentId) {


        Database.SaveResult result;

        Attachment attachment = new Attachment();
        attachment.body = this.fileBody;
        attachment.name = this.fileName;
        attachment.parentId = parentId;
        // insert the attahcment
        result = Database.insert(attachment);
        // reset the file for the view state
        fileBody = Blob.valueOf(' ');
        return result;
    }

    /**
    * Upload process is:
    *  1. Insert new Product_Review_Attachment__c record
    *  2. Insert new Attachment with the new Product_Review_Attachment__c record as parent
    *  3. Update the Product_Review_Attachment__c record with the ID of the new Attachment
    **/
    public PageReference processUpload() {

        if(description == null || description =='')
                {
                ApexPages.AddMessage(new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.ERROR, 
                'Could not save record without a description.'));
                    return null;
                }

       try {
            Database.SaveResult customAttachmentResult = saveCustomAttachment();

            if (customAttachmentResult == null || !customAttachmentResult.isSuccess()) {
                ApexPages.AddMessage(new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.ERROR, 
                  'Could not save attachment.'));
                return null;
                system.debug('customattachmentresult **************!!! ');
                return new PageReference('/'+contact.Id);
            }

            Database.SaveResult attachmentResult = saveStandardAttachment(customAttachmentResult.getId());

            if (attachmentResult == null || !attachmentResult.isSuccess()) {
                //ApexPages.AddMessage(new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.ERROR, 
                  //'Could not save attachment.'));            
                //return null;
                return new PageReference('/'+contact.Id);
            } else {
                // update the custom attachment record with some attachment info
                Product_Review_Attachment__c customAttachment = [select id from Product_Review_Attachment__c where id = :customAttachmentResult.getId()];
                customAttachment.name = this.fileName;
                customAttachment.Attachment__c = attachmentResult.getId();
                update customAttachment;
            }

       } catch (Exception e) {
          ApexPages.AddMessages(e);
          return null;
       }

        return new PageReference('/'+contact.Id);
    }

    public PageReference back() {
        return new PageReference('/'+contact.Id);
    }     
}
```

Thank you for any help.

My dilemma is that I am attempting to allow the user to save the record if they have included a Description, despite not including an actual file. So, I can't figure out how to allow it to successfully save the new record.

Comment: Add an if condition before this statment `Database.SaveResult attachmentResult = saveStandardAttachment(customAttachmentResult.getId());` like `if(fileBody != NULL)`

Comment: N.B. `attachmentResult == null` can never happen -- `Database.xxx` always returns a result object

Comment: My dilemma is that I am also attempting to allow the user to save the record if they have included a Description, despite not including an actual file. They can have one or the other but they can't miss both. So, I can't figure out how to allow it to successfully save the new record. I can't figure out of to do that.

Comment: So, it needs to be able to create the record, but it needs to be able to create a new Vendor_Review_Attachment__c record, but not attempt to create a file\attachment.

Comment: As it is now, I get a System error coming from "result = Database.insert(attachment);" if it attempts to create the record without an attachment being included.